# Schedule for every 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, web

I want to run a function every 10th minute in an hour. So for 10AM, the events will fire exactly at:

10:00
10:10
10:20
10:30
10:40
10:50

I'm aware of `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, however:
1. They're never exact. They're sometimes early, or delayed. They also get effected by being out of focus.
2. I'm not sure how to make a system (as I mentioned above) that will work with timeouts or intervals. 
3. Looking for the right way to do this.

**I'm not looking for a timer, but a scheduler.**

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: `They're never exact` - how precise are we talking?

Comment: alarm precise. I don't want things to get delayed even if they run for a week.

Comment: Is ~1 second off at max acceptable?

Comment: @Zettam where do you run this? client/server side?

Comment: @vitr clientside, web page.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst constant delay is acceptable, increasing delay is not

Comment: @Zettam, so, do you want to synchronise with user's time?

Comment: Yes :) ! That'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use NodeJS or other sync solution.
Easy way: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/06/how-to-build-a-realtime-jquery-plugin/

Comment: How would yo do that clientside?

Comment: I won't answer this, because this may get you in trouble. One of the coders rules - never trust clientside. I personally don't trust setInterval or setTimeout. What the sense? If clients browser did lag, then that's it - delay.

Comment: Well this is for a static webpage, no server side. In other words "trust" is not an issue. I just want this to work properly.

Comment: This is most accurate solution, I guess. https://github.com/mrchimp/tock 
Because it has self-correcting system inside. So, I would try to adapt this to your needs.